# Removing path separator at the end of the string

Tags: c

I'm using the following code to traverse a tree in backwards, and what I get right now is a separator at the end for example  child/grandchild/ <-- I want to remove that separator. I don't know what to modify in the algorithm to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node { struct node *parent; char *name; };

char *buildPath(node* node, bool use_register_name)
{
    struct node *temp = node;
    int length =0;
      do
      {
        length+=strlen(temp->name)+1; // for a slash;
        temp = temp->parent;
      } while(temp !=NULL);    
    char * buffer =malloc(length+1);
    buffer[0] = '\0';    
       do 
       {
         if(!use_register_name)
         {
            use_register_name=true;
            node = node->parent;
            continue;
         }
         char *name = strdup(node->name);
         strcat(buffer,"/");
         strrev(name);
         strcat(buffer,name);    

         node = node->parent;
         free(name);
       } while (node != NULL &&strcmp(node->name,"root")<0);    
    strrev(buffer);    
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node node1 = { NULL, "root" };
    struct node node2 = { &node1, "child" };
    struct node node3 = { &node2, "grandchild" };    
    char * result = buildPath(&node3, false);    
    printf(result);    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: it reverses the string name, and I use that name in the strcat

Comment: the issue is here 
`strrev(buffer);`
you must remove the slash after tthis command

Comment: as @Tim has said, replace `strrev(buffer);` by `strrev(buffer);buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that every output you get will have that trailing forward slash, you can simply remove it from the final output.  In the code snippet below, I conditionally check that the `result` has at least one character, and that the final character be a forward slash.  If these conditions are true, I remove the forward slash.

```
char * result = buildPath(&node3, false);

if (result && *result) {                      // make sure result has at least
    if (result[strlen(result) - 1] == '/')    // one character
        result[strlen(result) - 1] = 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Here is a solution to your problem which modifies the algorithm itself.  Try modifying your code to the following:

```
int firstCall = 1; // flag to keep track of whether this is first call (leaf node)

do {
    if(!use_register_name)
    {
        use_register_name=true;
        node = node->parent;
        continue;
    }
    char *name = strdup(node->name);
    if (firstCall) {
        firstCall = 0;
    }
    else {
        // ONLY add this slash to a non-terminal node
        strcat(buffer,"/");
    }
    strrev(name);
    strcat(buffer,name);

    node = node->parent;
    free(name);
} while (node != NULL &&strcmp(node->name,"root")<0);
```

Here is how your algorithm is currently building the path for the inputs in your OP:

```
buffer = "/dlihcdnarg"        // note carefully this leading (really trailing) slash
buffer = "/dlihcdnarg/dlihc"
```

Your code then reverses the buffer at some point to obtain this:

```
"child/grandchild/"
```

By adding a check for a leaf node, and not adding a leading (really trailing) slash in this case, you will get the following output:

```
"child/grandchild"
```

Comment: Can't I do it inside the algorithm?

Comment: Your code is very convoluted and I don't have access to a C compiler at the moment.  If you want to change the algorithm, then the way to do it is to change your logic.  Instead of adding a `/` at the _end_ at each step, you should be adding a `/` at the beginning of each step, _except_ for the root node, which does not get a _leading_ forward slash.

Comment: where is the beginning of each step, I'm confused. Where is the correct place of adding the the forward slash / ?

Comment: This is the point of my previous comment.  Your code is very confusing, and you are really the best person to go in there and debug, and figure out what is going on.  Basically, you should _not_ add the leading `/` when handling the root node, but every other node in the path should get a leading forward slash.  This of course will leave the last node _without_ a `/`, which is what you want.

Comment: @andre This is the way to remove trailing `/` char. In short `if ( str[strlen( str ) - 1] == '/' ) str[strlen( str ) - 1] = 0`. The other is cheking for null pointer or empty string.